# Can you please help me identify this 2-pin, weatherproof DC connector?

Tags: dc, identification, connector

I'm fixing an outdoor display item for a friend, and I need to replace the connector. I've pored over images from different Google searches, but I don't know if this type of connector has a special name. It is a 2-pin connector. The male pins have a D-shaped key to ensure proper polarity and are held in place by a plastic nut. I have several pictures of the connector, and I can provide dimensions if needed. If someone can point me in the direction of a vendor, that would also be helpful. I checked Jameco and McMaster-Carr, but I'm sure there are specialized suppliers that I don't know about.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: assembled plug]
[image: male plug showing D-molded key]
[image: female connector (don't need to replace this)]
[image: disassembled components]

Comment: You'll have to buy a unit with the exact same cable, as this design is most likely proprietary, all of it is plastic injection molded

Comment: It's a fairly common type of connector on Christmas lights.  But I have never seen one available as a stand-alone plug, only as something moulded onto a string of lights.

Comment: I'd say some horrible chinesium proprietary connector

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure how often manufacturers used their own unique configurations. Disappointing.
Thanks for your help!